# php class to insert array of values to oracle DB

Tags: php, arrays, oracle

I am trying to build a class that **insert array of values** into oracle database, I am also trying to make the class **scalable** (works with all forms of the application).

the reason am doing this is to reduce code repeating for the application am working on, **because it has a lot of forms, and some of them has a lot of variables (50+)**.. therefore I need to make a class capable of inserting values into table, where the number of values is dynamic (depending on the form).

so far what I did is:

```
class ArrayQuery {

    public $conn;
    public $table;


    public function __construct($conn){

        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public function setTableName($table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
    }

    public function InsertArray(array $args){

        $keys = array_keys($args);
        $values = array_values($args);

             // need help here //

    }
}
```

- The construct function will get database connection, by calling the $conn object from the db_connection class (e.g $conn = new db_connection(); $query = new ArrayQuery($conn);)
- setTableName is obviously for defining the desired table.
- now the ArrayQuery, what I did in my form page, I named the keys of the array the same as the name of columns in table, for example array args['id']= $_post['id']. so basically **array_key = column name**. I did that in order to get columns name without manually setting them.

now I have 2 arrays: **$keys** (holds the name of columns), and **$values** (holds the data to be insert).

I cant figure out **how to bind variables into keys? knowing that the number of variables is dynamic ?**

any help will be much appreciated

**UPDATE:**

Here is how the $args array are set

```
$args = array(
          'id' => $_POST['id'],
          'firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
          'lastname' => $_POST['lastname'],
          'email' => $_POsT['email'],
)
```

**answer:**

thanks to @calculon for putting me on the right track, with little modifications to work in my scenario, for future reference the answer to my case is:

```
$i=0; $col=''; $val='';
        foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
               if($i==0){
                 $col .= $key;
                 $val .= ':'.$key;
               }
               else{
               $col .= ', '.$key;
               $val .= ', :'.$key;
               }
               $i++;
         }

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.$col.') VALUES ('.$val.') ';
        $stmt = oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);
        foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
              oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $key, $args[$key]) ;
            }
        oci_execute($stmt);
```

hope it will be helpful, thanks again calculon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approximately such algorithm for inserting one row with an unknown number of columns I used in my project, for multiple rows should be added one more cycle

```
$i=0; $keys=''; $vals='';
foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
       if($i==0){
         $keys .= ''.$key;
         $vals .= ':'.$key;
       }
       $keys .= ', '.$key;
       $vals .= ', :'.$key;
       $i++;
 }
$sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.$keys.') VALUES ('.$vals.') ';
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
      oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $key, $args[$key]) ;
    }
oci_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Hi calculon, thanks for the answer. could u explain it more if u please. I think there is some typing mistakes here, shouldn't $val .= ':'.$key; be $val .= ':'.$val; instead? and what do u mean with ($==0)?, thanks.

Comment: `$val .= ':'.$key;` this line forms just a place for the variable-binding function, then `oci_bind_by_name` will put the required value.
`$==0` should be `($i==0)`

Comment: hi, Its not working mate, I get errors:
- illegal variable name/number
- duplicate column name
-  oci_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null gi

Comment: since the $args array keys equal to column names, shouldn't the $key and $val be arrays? thus we say $key[i] instead of $key in the loop?

Comment: I wrote an algorithm that inserts only one string array, the input must have the following structure ('column name'=>'current cell value', e.t.c). What is your structure of array 'args'?

Comment: $args structure is 'column-name' => 'inserted value'

Comment: ok the error is here: oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $key, $args[$key]);
 
error-message: illegal variable name/number

Comment: your method got me to the right track, there was only one mistake that made it not working..  $keys .= ''.$key; should be $keys .= $key; when i=0 and i added else and brackets because I noticed it generates duplicated output, e.g. $keys = id, id and vals= :id, :id. when encapsulating inside brackets it works just fine, ill add the correct method for future reference. and thank you very much for the help :)